# How do I convert a ObservableCollection(Of T) to List(Of T) an in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, observablecollection, generic-list

I am working on VB.net windows8 mobile application in this app i am facing conversion issue.
I am adding the new service reference in our application and previous old service reference is changed.

old code:

```
Dim JobAllDetailsList As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of JobAllDetails)
JobAllDetailsList = e.Result
JobAllDetails---->class interface.
```

Newcode:

new service model is `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`.

How to convert `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection` to System.Collections.Generic.List? please give me suggestion or help.

Comment: In C#, I use `.ToList()` which is under the namespace `using System.Linq;`. Do that in VB.

Comment: This only happened (after) you added a new service reference?

Comment: Hi amar,Thank you for your time and support .ToList() is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call `.ToList()` from your `ObservableCollection(Of T)`, for example :

```
JobAllDetailsList = e.Result.ToList()
```

Comment: Dim JobAllDetailsList As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of JobAllDetails) JobAllDetailsList.Add(e.Result) here .ToList() is not supporting

Comment: HI friend thank you for your kind support and issue is resolved .